# Autoresizing on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have a UITableView in my iOS application, and depending on the device (iPhone or iPad), I size different items on my UITableView's contentViews.

For example, every cell's contentView has something called a valueLabel. Depending on the device, I size it properly:

```
if(IDIOM == IPAD)
    valueLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 430.0, 0.0, 216, 44.0 )] autorelease];
else
    valueLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 165.0, 0.0, 80, 44.0 )] autorelease];
```

Then, I configure the label (color, font, etc) and after that, I have the following lines of code:

```
if(IDIOM != IPAD)
     valueLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Turns out, when I first wrote this, I was smart for doing this. But I can't remember why. I'm trying to make an update which supports landscape mode on both the iPhone and iPad. But only the UITableView on the iPhone sizes properly in landscape mode, because for the iPad, I don't have Autoresizing. How can I have autoresizing on the iPad?

If I remove the condition `if(IDIOM != IPAD)`, the labels don't even show up, and my cells are empty.

Comment: Remove the condition `IDIOM != IPAD`?

Comment: If I remove the condition if(IDIOM != IPAD), the labels don't even show up, and my cells are empty.

Comment: i assume you mean, the labels don't show up on iPhone (if you remove the conditional statement)

Comment: often, setting the background to pink or some other garish color will help you see them, and you can watch where they may be moving when you change orientation; also `gdb` is quite useful here, break in an obvious place and `po [someView subViews]` to see all the frames of the subviews and where they might be (non visibly), it could give you a hint to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think views in IPad can be Autoresized. But you can manage your views according to orientation. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382119/rearrange-object-in-table-view-for-different-orientation-of-ipad/6383399#6383399).

Comment: Perhaps it was true at the time, but I can confirm that autoresizing *does* work on UIViews on iOS 5.0 and Xcode 4.4

Answer (score 0):

Is the outer container the iPad table view is located in on the iPad resizing?

Comment: What do you mean? My UITableView is on my UITableViewController. But even without rotating the device, if I don't include that if statement, I can't see the labels. Why does autoresizing mess up on the iPad?

Comment: It could be the auto-resizing mask is allowing the labels you have to get shifted totally out of the boundary of the cell, the X origin at 430 seems really weird to me.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean... sorry I can't help further.