# Unable to understand the orientation in iphone programming?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, orientation

I am writing code in ViewDidLoad as following,

```
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)                                               name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil]; 
    //Whenever the device orientation changes, orientationChanged will be called
```

and the body of orientationChanged: Method is following

```
    - (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

        NSLog(@"Method is Called"); 

        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
        //self.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(-50, -70, 800, 900);

        //Based upon which orientation the device is in, update your View rotations.
        //A simple view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(whatever); will work well.
    }
```

I am unable to understand the behavior of this method, can any body tell me that what these two lines will do, the first one change frame of self.view.frame, and second one for superview which I did commented.

Thanks in Advance Saeen

Comment: why your using NSNotificationCenter for this

Comment: simply, I found from stack :-(

Comment: i add code below try with that code and you can call that method from viewWillAppear with present orientation like [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation duration:0.2];

Answer (score 2):

You can manage your views according to orientation. Check my answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382119/rearrange-object-in-table-view-for-different-orientation-of-ipad/6383399#6383399).

Answer (score 0):

use this insted of notification center it work fine

```
    -(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

    - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
    {
        appDelegate.interface=interfaceOrientation;
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {  
        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            txt_description.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
            appDelegate.screenWidth = 1024;
            img_background.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748);
            img_background.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background_ipad_landscape" ofType:@"png"]];

            lbl_friendName.frame=CGRectMake(185, 58, 180, 30);
            btn_friendName.frame=CGRectMake(390, 60, 436, 27);
            [btn_friendName setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dropdown_s14_ipad_landscape" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            lbl_friendNameValue.frame=CGRectMake(399, 59, 300, 30);
            lbl_date.frame=CGRectMake(185, 110, 180, 30);
            btn_date.frame=CGRectMake(390, 110, 436, 27);
            [btn_date setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dropdown_s14_ipad_landscape" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            lbl_dateValue.frame=CGRectMake(399, 109, 300, 30);
            lbl_category.frame=CGRectMake(185, 160, 180, 30);
            btn_category.frame=CGRectMake(390, 160, 436, 27);
            [btn_category setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dropdown_s14_ipad_landscape" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            lbl_categoryValue.frame=CGRectMake(399, 159, 300, 30);
            //btn_radio2.frame=CGRectMake(199, 128, 21, 21);
            lbl_amount.frame=CGRectMake(185, 210, 180, 30);
            txt_amount.frame=CGRectMake(390, 210, 436, 31);
            lbl_currency.frame=CGRectMake(185, 260, 180, 30);
            lbl_currencyValue.frame=CGRectMake(399, 258, 330, 30);
            btn_currency.frame = CGRectMake(390, 260, 436, 27);
            [btn_currency setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dropdown_s14_ipad_landscape" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            lbl_typeofCost.frame=CGRectMake(185, 310, 180, 30);
            btn_radio1.frame = CGRectMake(390, 310, 21, 21);
            lbl_allocate.frame = CGRectMake(420, 308, 180, 27);
            btn_radio2.frame = CGRectMake(600, 310, 21, 21);
            lbl_share.frame = CGRectMake(630, 308, 180, 27);
            lbl_typeofCostValue.frame=CGRectMake(399, 348, 430, 30);
            btn_typeofCost.frame = CGRectMake(390, 350, 436, 27);
            [btn_typeofCost setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dropdown_s14_ipad_landscape" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            lbl_Description.frame=CGRectMake(185, 394, 180, 30);
            img_inputbox.frame=CGRectMake(390, 400, 436, 61);
            img_inputbox.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"input_box_s14_1_ipad_landscape" ofType:@"png"]];
            txt_description.frame=CGRectMake(395, 405, 436, 53);
            lbl_placeholder.frame=CGRectMake(402, 405, 350, 21);
            btn_save.frame=CGRectMake(430, 550, 128, 51);
            scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 800);
            lbl_colon1.frame = CGRectMake(378, 58, 5, 30); 
            lbl_colon2.frame = CGRectMake(378, 108, 5, 30);
            lbl_colon3.frame = CGRectMake(378, 158, 5, 30);
            lbl_colon4.frame = CGRectMake(378, 208, 5, 30);
            lbl_colon5.frame = CGRectMake(378, 258, 5, 30);
            lbl_colon6.frame = CGRectMake(378, 304, 5, 30);
            lbl_colon7.frame = CGRectMake(378, 392, 5, 30);

        }
        else
        {
            appDelegate.screenWidth=480;
            [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 440)];
            img_background.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 480,320);
            img_topbar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 44);
            img_background.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background_landscape" ofType:@"png"]];
            //lbl_head.frame=CGRectMake(160, 9, 159, 33);

            lbl_friendName.frame=CGRectMake(13, 30, 110, 21);
            btn_friendName.frame=CGRectMake(130, 27, 286, 27);
            [btn_friendName setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"drop-down_s6_landscape" ofType:@"png"]] forState:0];


            lbl_date.frame=CGRectMake(13, 67, 95, 21);
            btn_date.frame=CGRectMake(130, 64, 286, 27);
            [btn_date setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"drop-down_s6_landscape" ofType:@"png"]] forState:0];

            lbl_category.frame=CGRectMake(13, 106, 95, 21);
            btn_category.frame=CGRectMake(130, 102, 286, 27);
            [btn_category setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"drop-down_s6_landscape" ofType:@"png"]] forState:0];
                        //btn_radio2.frame=CGRectMake(199, 128, 21, 21);
            lbl_amount.frame=CGRectMake(13, 143, 95, 21);
            txt_amount.frame=CGRectMake(130, 140, 286, 31);
            lbl_currency.frame=CGRectMake(13, 182, 95, 21);
            btn_currency.frame = CGRectMake(130, 179, 286, 27);
            [btn_currency setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"drop-down_s6_landscape" ofType:@"png"]] forState:0];

            lbl_typeofCost.frame=CGRectMake(13, 212, 95, 21);
            btn_radio1.frame=CGRectMake(130, 212, 21, 21);
            lbl_allocate.frame = CGRectMake(155, 212, 100, 21);
            btn_radio2.frame = CGRectMake(275, 212, 21, 21);
            lbl_share.frame = CGRectMake(310, 212, 80, 21);
            btn_typeofCost.frame = CGRectMake(130, 240, 286, 27);
            lbl_typeofCostValue.frame = CGRectMake(135, 242, 250, 21);
            [btn_typeofCost setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"drop-down_s6_landscape" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            //[btn_provideDate setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dropdown_s5.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            lbl_Description.frame=CGRectMake(13, 276, 150, 21);
            img_inputbox.frame=CGRectMake(130, 275, 286, 61);
            img_inputbox.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"input_box_s42_landscape" ofType:@"png"]];
            txt_description.frame=CGRectMake(135, 281, 276, 45);
            lbl_placeholder.frame=CGRectMake(142, 278, 200, 21);
            btn_save.frame=CGRectMake(190, 345, 108, 41);
            //btn_adv.frame=CGRectMake(0, 175, 480, 48);
            lbl_colon1.frame = CGRectMake(119, 27, 5, 27); 
            lbl_colon2.frame = CGRectMake(119, 63, 5, 27);
            lbl_colon3.frame = CGRectMake(119, 102, 5, 27);
            lbl_colon4.frame = CGRectMake(119, 140, 5, 27);
            lbl_colon5.frame = CGRectMake(119, 179, 5, 27);
            lbl_colon6.frame = CGRectMake(119, 208, 5, 27);
            lbl_colon7.frame = CGRectMake(119, 272, 5, 27);
            [self displayProperFontSize];
            }


        }
        if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        { 

            if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            {
            txt_description.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
            appDelegate.screenWidth=768;
            img_background.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004);
            img_background.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background_ipad" ofType:@"png"]];

            lbl_friendName.frame=CGRectMake(105, 65, 180, 30);
            btn_friendName.frame=CGRectMake(310, 67, 316, 27);
            [btn_friendName setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dropdown_s6_ipad" ofType:@"png"]] forState:0];
            lbl_friendNameValue.frame=CGRectMake(318, 66, 280, 28);
            lbl_date.frame=CGRectMake(105, 116, 180, 30);
            btn_date.frame=CGRectMake(310, 116, 316, 27);
            [btn_date setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dropdown_s6_ipad" ofType:@"png"]] forState:0];
            lbl_dateValue.frame=CGRectMake(315, 116, 278, 26);
            lbl_category.frame=CGRectMake(105, 164, 180, 30);
            btn_category.frame=CGRectMake(310, 166, 316, 27);
            [btn_category setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dropdown_s6_ipad" ofType:@"png"]] forState:0];
            lbl_categoryValue.frame=CGRectMake(318, 167, 273, 26);
            //btn_radio2.frame=CGRectMake(199, 128, 21, 21);
            lbl_amount.frame=CGRectMake(105, 210, 180, 30);
            txt_amount.frame=CGRectMake(310, 210, 316, 31);
            lbl_currency.frame=CGRectMake(105, 260, 180, 30);
            btn_currency.frame = CGRectMake(310, 258,316, 33);
            lbl_currencyValue.frame=CGRectMake(316, 260, 310, 30);
            [btn_currency setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dropdown_s6_ipad" ofType:@"png"]] forState:0];
            lbl_typeofCost.frame=CGRectMake(105, 310, 180, 30);
            btn_radio1.frame=CGRectMake(310, 318, 21, 21);
            lbl_allocate.frame = CGRectMake(340, 318, 100, 21);
            btn_radio2.frame = CGRectMake(445, 318, 21, 21);
            lbl_share.frame = CGRectMake(475, 318, 200, 21);
            btn_typeofCost.frame = CGRectMake(310, 357,316, 33);
            lbl_typeofCostValue.frame=CGRectMake(315, 359, 310, 30);
            [btn_typeofCost setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dropdown_s6_ipad" ofType:@"png"]] forState:0];
            //[btn_provideDate setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dropdown_s5.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            lbl_Description.frame=CGRectMake(105, 400, 180, 30);
            img_inputbox.frame=CGRectMake(310, 410, 316, 61);
            img_inputbox.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"input_box_s42_1_ipad" ofType:@"png"]];
            txt_description.frame=CGRectMake(316, 414, 310, 53);
            lbl_placeholder.frame = CGRectMake(322, 414, 290, 21);

            lbl_colon1.frame = CGRectMake(300, 65, 7, 30); 
            lbl_colon2.frame = CGRectMake(300, 114, 7, 30);
            lbl_colon3.frame = CGRectMake(300, 164, 7, 30);
            lbl_colon4.frame = CGRectMake(300, 209, 7, 30);
            lbl_colon5.frame = CGRectMake(300, 260, 7, 30);
            lbl_colon6.frame = CGRectMake(300, 313, 7, 30);
            lbl_colon7.frame = CGRectMake(300, 402, 7, 30);

            btn_save.frame=CGRectMake(300, 550, 128, 51);
            } 
            else
            {
               appDelegate.screenWidth=320;
               [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
                img_background.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,480);
                img_background.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background" ofType:@"png"]];
                lbl_friendName.frame=CGRectMake(8, 16, 97, 34);
                btn_friendName.frame=CGRectMake(114, 20, 196, 27);
                [btn_friendName setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dropdown_s6" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            lbl_friendNameValue.frame=CGRectMake(121, 20, 170, 28);
            lbl_date.frame=CGRectMake(8, 59, 95, 21);
            btn_date.frame=CGRectMake(114, 56, 196, 27);
            [btn_date setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dropdown_s6" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            lbl_dateValue.frame=CGRectMake(121, 53, 170, 34);
            lbl_category.frame=CGRectMake(8, 96, 95, 21);
            btn_category.frame=CGRectMake(114, 94, 196, 27);
            [btn_category setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dropdown_s6" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            lbl_categoryValue.frame=CGRectMake(120, 90, 166, 34);
            //btn_radio2.frame=CGRectMake(199, 128, 21, 21);
            lbl_amount.frame=CGRectMake(8, 136, 95, 21);
            txt_amount.frame=CGRectMake(114, 131, 196, 31);
            lbl_currency.frame=CGRectMake(8, 170, 95, 21);

            btn_currency.frame =CGRectMake(114, 170, 196, 27);
            [btn_currency setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dropdown_s6" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            lbl_typeofCost.frame=CGRectMake(8, 205, 95, 21);
            btn_radio1.frame=CGRectMake(114, 205, 21, 21);
            lbl_allocate.frame = CGRectMake(140, 205, 80, 21);
            btn_radio2.frame = CGRectMake(220, 205, 21, 21);
            lbl_share.frame = CGRectMake(245, 199, 65, 34);
            btn_typeofCost.frame = CGRectMake(114, 233, 196, 27);
            lbl_typeofCostValue.frame = CGRectMake(119, 229, 170, 34);
            [btn_typeofCost setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dropdown_s6" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            //[btn_provideDate setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dropdown_s5.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            lbl_Description.frame=CGRectMake(8, 265, 95, 21);
            img_inputbox.frame=CGRectMake(114, 267, 196, 51);
            img_inputbox.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"input_box_s16" ofType:@"png"]];
            txt_description.frame=CGRectMake(117, 274, 185, 37);
            lbl_placeholder.frame = CGRectMake(124, 270, 160, 21);
            btn_save.frame=CGRectMake(109, 326, 88, 41);

            lbl_colon1.frame = CGRectMake(105, 20, 5, 27); 
            lbl_colon2.frame = CGRectMake(105, 55, 5, 27);
            lbl_colon3.frame = CGRectMake(105, 94, 5, 27);
            lbl_colon4.frame = CGRectMake(105, 133, 5, 27);
            lbl_colon5.frame = CGRectMake(105, 168, 5, 27);
            lbl_colon6.frame = CGRectMake(105, 201, 5, 27);
            lbl_colon7.frame = CGRectMake(105, 262, 5, 27);
            [self displayProperFontSize];
            }   
        }
        [appDelegate adjustTab];


    }
```

Comment: let me search this term, I would be thankful if you provide a bit code of few lines, I want to change labels CGRectMake according to Orientation along with animation.

Comment: Wao..it seems very simple and effortless :D

Answer (score 0):

this metod will call when ever you rotate the device you can set frame in this method

```
     - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
        {
        if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
           self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 300);

        }
        else
        {
           self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);

        }
     }
```